# Angular2 UnitTest

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I would need a tips for testing angular. I have component which I should test it, and now need help how to do it.

```
export class RadioButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input('group')
  private _group: RadioGroupComponent;

  @ViewChild('radio', {static: true})
  private _matRadioButton: MatRadioButton;

  @Input('item')
  public item: any;

  public setSelected() {
    this._matRadioButton.checked = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._matRadioButton.radioGroup = this._group.getMatRadioGroup();
    this._group.addRadioButton(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._matRadioButton.radioGroup = null;
    this._group.removeRadioButton(this);
  }
}
```

How do I try to test is:

```
import { SharedModule } from './../../../app/shared/shared.module';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RadioButtonComponent } from 'src/core';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RadioGroupComponent } from './radiogroup.component';



describe('RadioButtonComponent', () => {
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<RadioButtonComponent>;
   let component: RadioButtonComponent;
   beforeEach( async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports:[SharedModule],
       schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
     });

     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RadioButtonComponent);
     component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
     component['_group'] = new RadioGroupComponent();
     component['_group'].writeValue('test');
     component.ngAfterViewInit();
     fixture.detectChanges();


   }));

   describe('setSelected()', () => {
      it('should be selected', () => {

          const result = component.setSelected();

          expect(result).toBeTruthy();
     });
   });
});
```

Basically my error is:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I need help to figure out how to manage correctly unit test,so test can pass.
Do you have any suggestion how I can run test successfully ?

Kind Regards,
Danijel

Comment: are you really using angular2? can you be more specific on what version of angular you using?

Comment: I cant see `value` anywhere in your code. Is it in your `RadioGroupComponent` ??

Comment: Correct value is property of RadioGroupComponent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few details missing in your post but....

Try to remove de redundant describe method, secondly you are not returning anything in the setSelected() method so it will always be false, try instead to check if the radio button component variable if it gets checked or not with following(help with [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync)):

```
it('should be selected', fakeAsync() => {

  let status = component._matRadioButton.checked

  expect(status).toBeFalsy();

  component.setSelected();

  tick(15);

  expect(status).toBeTruthy();

});
```

**UPDATE:**
either change _matRadioButton to public or refactor your setSelected method in order to read the action to something like:

```
setSelected(): Boolean {
  let result = this._matRadioButton.checked ? this._matRadioButton.checked = false : this._matRadioButton.checked = true
  return result;
}
```

Comment: let status = component._matRadioButton.checked can not be used like that _matRadioButton is private method...

Answer (score 0):

I had found the way.First I had must instantiate RadioButtonGroupComponent

```
const radioButtonGroupComponent: RadioButtonGroupComponent = new RadioButtonGroupComponent();
```

Later after RadioButtonComponent is created by ComponentFixture I had assigned instance.

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RadioButtonComponent);
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
component['_group'] =  radioButtonGroupComponent
```

And at the end to get run successfully test code is:

```
 it('sholud be selected', () => {
    component.setSelected();
    const status = component['_matRadioButton'].checked;
    expect(status).toBeTruthy();
  });
```